# Liquid | Jekyll - For loop with 2 conditions and with limit?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to get the first post.content from a list of posts that belongs to  two (or multiple) different categories.

The following does work, but does not exclude all but the first result:

```
{% for post in site.categories.categorie_A and for post in site.categories.categorie_B %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Placing a limit on this, will result in nothing (while it should work):

```
{% for post in site.categories.categorie_A and for post in site.categories.categorie_B limit:1 %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not work either:

```
{% for post in site.categories.categorie_A limit:1 and for post in site.categories.categorie_B limit:1 %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Even an if statement does not make this work:

```
{% for post in site.categories.categorie_A and for post in site.categories.categorie_B %}
    {% if forloop.first == true %}
          {{ post.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Aswell as nested for loops:

```
{% for post in site.categories.categorie_A %}
    {% for categorie_A_post in post.categories.categorie_B %}
        {{ categorie_A_post.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or something like :

```
{% for p in site.posts %}
  {% if p.categories contains "categorie_A" and p.categories contains "categorie_B" %}
    <p>{{ p.title }}</p>
    {% break %}{% comment %}Exit the loop{% endcomment %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: very nice, i was wondering how the break would work within liquid, i think nesting the categories within (if's) is cleaner way to go, going by everything i read on liquid

Answer (score 0):

I found this works, not pretty but it works.

```
          {% for post in site.posts %}
              {% if post.categories contains "categorie_A" and post.categories contains "categorie_B" %}
                  {% capture times_if %}{% increment times_if %}{% endcapture %}
                  {% if times_if == '0' %}
                      {{ post.content }}
                  {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

and a little bit cleaner (without "and")

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.categories contains "categorie_A" %}
        {% if post.categories contains "categorie_B" %}
            {% capture times_if %}{% increment times_if %}{% endcapture %}
            {% if times_if == '0' %}
                {{ post.content }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It it also possible to write this using the forloop variable. The forloop variable also works in case you want the second or third result:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.categories contains "categorie_A" and post.categories contains "categorie_B" %}
    {% if forloop.first == true %}
      {{ post.content }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Learn more about this variable [here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops). Good luck!